# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "bouton" is not found

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I have a problem with the discord bot I am trying to create.
First I used the button, but it doesn't seem to be the right way with "discord-components"
I then found that "discord-components" package is no longer developed since 2021
So I went to use another way, now I use "discord.ui.Button" instead

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Connecté en tant que {bot.user} !")

@bot.command()
async def bouton(ctx):
    try:
        button1 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="Bouton WOW !", custom_id="bouton1")
        button2 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, label="Bouton 2", custom_id="bouton2")
        button3 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, label="Bouton 3", custom_id="bouton3")
        
        view = discord.ui.View()
        view.add_item(button1)
        view.add_item(button2)
        view.add_item(button3)

        await ctx.send("Bonjour tout le monde !", view=view)

        interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        if interaction.component.custom_id == "bouton1":
            await interaction.respond(content="Bouton 1 cliqué !")
        elif interaction.component.custom_id == "bouton2":
            await interaction.respond(content="Bouton 2 cliqué !")
        elif interaction.component.custom_id == "bouton3":
            await interaction.respond(content="Bouton 3 cliqué !")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Une erreur s'est produite : {e}")
    pass
    
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

When I call with `!bouton` it will send what I want, but the button doesn't work

[Message sended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGBQu.jpg)

In the console I can see this error

```
2024-03-10 16:37:40 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "bouton" is not found
```

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrFhP.jpg)

Anyone have an idea?

User in discord must be able to use the button